# cfhttp to get an image and save to the disk

Tags: image, coldfusion

I am trying to get an image from a url and save it to the local using cfhttp like below.

```
<cfhttp
    timeout="45"
    throwonerror="false"
    url="http://domain/images/cme_recorder_on.png"
    method="get"
    useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.8.1.12) Gecko/20080201 Firefox/2.0.0.12"
    getasbinary="yes"
    result="local.objGet"
>

<cfset myImage = ImageNew(local.objGet.FileContent)>

<cfif (FindNoCase( "200", local.objGet.Statuscode ) AND FindNoCase( "image", local.objGet.Responseheader["Content-Type"]
        ))>   
      <cfoutput>this is an image</cfoutput>
       <cffile file="#myImage#" action="write" output="c:\test_myImage.jpg"> 
<cfelse>
     <cfabort>   
</cfif>
```

I have tried using cffile write to save the image to the local. I do not see any image being writted into c:. Is this the right way to save the image to disk? Thanks all

Comment: Try switching the file and output attributes in cffile.  the file attribute should be the filename.

Comment: I tried switching the two, still do not see the image being written.

Comment: Maybe you are not checking in the C:\ of the coldfusion server. Your code works fine for the conditions. Include the Imagewrite function as @Sean suggested instead of cffile and check for the image created in the C:\ of the coldfusion server.

Comment: Does the "this is an image" text display?

Comment: Why not just do the save in your cfhttp call? See the tag's `file` and `path` attributes. Though as Sean mentioned, you should still check the status of the http call, to verify it succeeded.

Comment: Yes It is being saved, i was looking in my local! thanks for your replies.

Comment: Just curious.. is there a specific reason for using ImageNew + cffile, instead of using cfhttp to save to file directly? Unless you need to display or manipulate the image, the extra calls are unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `imageWrite()` https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/ImageWrite

So for your example, instead of using `cffile` you would use

```
<cfset imageWrite(myImage, "c:\test_myImage.jpg") />
```

Comment: This does not write it either!

Comment: OK, well you need to check your code then.  You are writing it within a condition.  Do you get a 200 back?  Do you get image in the content type header?  Unless both of those are actually true you wont get it to write.  ImageWrite will absolutely write an image read from a CFHTTP request and parsed as an image with ImageNew() so, again, check your code.  Or update above to indicate what you are doing now.  Simplify your example.  Take the condition out, for starters.

Answer (score 4):

The source for `imageNew` can be a URL, so there's no need for `cfhttp` in this case.

```
<cfset newImage = imageNew( "http://domain/images/cme_recorder_on.png" )>
<cfset imageWrite(newImage, "c:\test_myImage.jpg")>
```

Comment: True. Though since it is ultimately about making an http request, cfhttp might serve better here.  It provides a lot more details about the request in the case of problems (404 error, timeout, etcetera). Plus it can save the content directly to a file: no extra functions needed. However, if they need to manipulate the image first, then using ImageNew would make more sense.